# How can I add characters at the beginning and end of every non-empty line in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to use this:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(.*)$/\"$1\",/g' /path/to/your/file
```

for adding " at beginning of line and ", at end of each line in text file. The problem is that some lines are just empty lines and I don't want these to be altered. Any ideas how to modify above code or maybe do it completely differently?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Others have already answered the regex syntax issue, let's look at that style.

```
s/^(.*)$/\"$1\",/g
```

This regex suffers from "leaning toothpick syndrome" where /// makes your brain bleed.

```
s{^ (.+) $}{ "$1", }x;
```

Use of balanced delimiters, the /x modifier to space things out and elimination of unnecessary backwhacks makes the regex far easier to read.  Also the /g is unnecessary as this regex is only ever going to match once per line.

Answer (score 7):

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(.+)$/\"$1\",/g' /your/file
```

.* matches 0 or more characters; .+ matches 1 or more.

You may also want to replace the `.+` with `.*\S.*` to ensure that only lines containing a non-whitespace character are quoted.

Answer (score 4):

change .* to .+

In other words lines must contain at 1 or more characters. .* represents zero or more characters.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to just replace the `*` (0 or more) with a `+` (1 or more), like so:

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(.+)$/\"$1\",/g' /path/to/your/file
```

Answer (score 4):

all you are doing is adding something to the front and back of the line, so there is no need for regex. Just print them out. Regex for such a task is expensive if your file is big.

gawk

```
$ awk 'NF{print "\042" $0 "\042,"}' file
```

or Perl

```
$ perl -ne 'chomp;print "\042$_\042,\n" if ($_ ne "") ' file
```

Comment: Doesn't that modify the empty lines too? He said he didn't want that.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, in the Perl version, you want `if $_ ne ''` rather than just `if $_`.  `$_` will evaluate as false for certain non-empty lines (specifically, those containing a lone 0).

Comment: good point. no i don't think you are being pedantic since its a very logical bug. fixed && thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -r 's/(.+)/"\1"/' /path/to/your/file
```